# Cancelling previous API requests with Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to follow Axios documentation to cancel repeated requests to an URL but while I get no errors the requests aren't being cancelled. I still can do as many as I want through the following method.

```
import axios from 'axios'

getData({commit,state,dispatch}, id){
      const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      const source = CancelToken.source();
      axios
      .get("http://15.100.100.100:9999/getData/" + id,{
        cancelToken: source.token
      }).catch(function (thrown) {
        if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
          console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
        } else {
          console.log("cancel error")
        }
      })
    },
```

I followed Axios documentation found here https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

EDIT: Kaushik Makwana's answer was correct but in my case, instead of saving in a regular variable, i saved it in a state since my axios calls are made in my store.js file.

Comment: Where do you call source.cancel() ?

Comment: Can you explain what type of error occurred?

Comment: I get no errors @KaushikMakwana

Comment: where should i call source.cancel()? @Blitz

Comment: you have to call source.cancel() for cancel the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set a global variable to store past request.

```
 var source;
    getData({commit,state,dispatch}, id){

              if(source){
                 source.cancel();
              }
              const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
              source = CancelToken.source();
              axios
              .get("http://15.100.100.100:9999/getData/" + id,{
                cancelToken: source.token
              }).catch(function (thrown) {
                if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
                  console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
                } else {
                  console.log("cancel error")
                }
              })
            },
```

Comment: hum, so in this case my source would be the url i am using in my api call?

Comment: the source will be instance of CancelToken.source();

Comment: just to let you know it worked, the only difference is that i saved my source in a state instead on a regular variable.

Answer (score 5):

Using inside componentDidMount lifecycle hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source() // <-- 1st step

const fetchPost = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get(`endpointURL`, {
      cancelToken: ourRequest.token, // <-- 2nd step
    })
    console.log(response.data)

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('There was a problem or request was cancelled.')
  }
}
fetchPost()

return () => {
  ourRequest.cancel() // <-- 3rd step
}
}, [])
```

Note: For POST request, pass cancelToken as 3rd argument

```
Axios.post(`endpointURL`, {data}, {
 cancelToken: ourRequest.token, // 2nd step
})
```