# Cancel axios request, if response from server comes after 10 seconds

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using **axios** in my react-native application to make api calls. What I need to do is to **cancel the api request** and show a Something went wrong screen if 10 seconds have passed and yet there is no response.
Let me know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Wouldnt it be more correct to hook on the error handler of axios?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382537/cancelling-previous-api-requests-with-axios

Comment: export const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let source = CancelToken.source();

source && source.cancel('Operation canceled due to new request.');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the timeout (default is about 5 seconds) and also can use this:

for adding a timeout:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 10000, // in miliseconds
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

for axios v0.22.0:

```
const controller = new AbortController();
controller.abort()
```

for older versions:

```
CancelToken
```

[Check this for more information](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)

Comment: How do you configure the timeout seconds to 10 seconds in this?